# Making image absolute messes it up (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, twitter-bootstrap, sass, slim-lang

I'm trying to create a Bootstrap carousel with images that have text over them. To do that, I need to make the position of the images in the carousel absolute. Here is an image in the carousel before I made it absolute

[image]

I need the testimonials and this is LA text over the image. So I make it absolute and this happens

[image]

And no matter what I do, I can't seem to fix it.

Here is my Slim markup

```
.container#testimonialsSection
    .carousel.slide#testimoniesCarousel data-ride="carousel"
      ol
        li data-target="#testimoniesCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"
        li data-target="#testimoniesCarousel" data-slide-to="1" class="active"
        li data-target="#testimoniesCarousel" data-slide-to="2" class="active"
        li data-target="#testimoniesCarousel" data-slide-to="3" class="active"
        li data-target="#testimoniesCarousel" data-slide-to="4" class="active"
      .carousel-inner role="listbox"
        .item.active
          = image_tag("losangelesskyline.jpg", :class => "img-responsive")
          h2.center Testimonials
          p This is LA
        .item
          = image_tag("newyorkskyline.jpg")
          p This is NY
        .item
          = image_tag("miamiskyline.jpg")
          p This is Miami
        .item
          = image_tag("bostonskyline.jpg")
          p This is Boston
        .item
          = image_tag("atlantaskyline.jpg")
          p This is Atlanta
      a.left.carousel-control href="#testimoniesCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev" onclick=""
        span.glyphicon.glyphicon-chevron-left aria-hidden="true"
        span.sr-only Previous
      a.right.carousel-control href="#testimoniesCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next" onclick=""
        span.glyphicon.glyphicon-chevron-right aria-hidden="true"
        span.sr-only Next
```

And here is my SCSS

```
.carousel-control.left, .carousel-control.right {
    background-image: none
}

#testimonialsSection {
    height: 70%;
    width: 100%;
}

#testimoniesCarousel {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    h3 {
        font-size: 300%;
    }
    p {
        text-align: center;
        margin-left: 5%;
        margin-right: 5%;
        font-size: 200% !important;
    }
    img {
        position: absolute;
        height: 70%;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .carousel-control.left .glyphicon {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 35%;
        margin-left: 0;
        color: #D6D6D6;
    }
    .carousel-control.right .glyphicon {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 35%;
        margin-right: 0;
        color: #D6D6D6;
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I just remembered that it scales with the amount of content. Once I added my text to it the image expanded. It works now